# Does calling empty class methods affect performance?

Tags: c++, performance, visual-studio-2005

Timer.h:

```
class Timer
{
public:
void start();
void printTimeAndRestart(const char* msg);
};
namespace Timing {    static Timer timer; }
```

Timer.cpp:

```
#ifdef DO_TIMING
//implementation
void Timer::start() { ... };
void Timer::printTimeAndRestart(const char* msg) { ... };
#else
//empty - do not do timing
void Timer::start() {};
void Timer::printTimeAndRestart(const char* /*msg*/) {};
#endif
```

timer will be used in a lot of different files like:

```
Timing::timer.start(); 
... 
Timing::timer.printTimeAndRestart("Operation X took :");
```

If application is very performance sensitive and timers are called often, would calling empty methods when DO_TIMING is not defined affect performance? What would be a better option of implementing isolated timer (no need to recompile whole project to turn on/off), that is not affecting performance at all when is off.

So far I can think only of defining macros like

```
#ifdef DO_TIMING 
#define START_TIMING()
Timing::timer.start(); 
#endif
#else
#define START_TIMING()
#endif
```

and using them instead of Timing::timer.start(); but that would require recompiling whole code to turn them on/off...

Comment: Not yet - in process of implementing it as written above, but I posted to see what are the other design options/if it is possible to tell if performance will be affected right away just by looking at desing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A high quality compiler will probably remove it regardless, but it's safer to ensure that the empty function is inlined in the .h file:

Timer.h

```
class Timer
{
public:
  void start();
  void printTimeAndRestart(const char* msg);
};

#ifndef DO_TIMING

inline void Timer::start() {}
inline void printTimeAndRestart(const char* msg) {}

#endif

namespace Timing {    static Timer timer; }
```

Timer.cpp

```
#ifdef DO_TIMING

// ...

#endif
```

Unfortunately this does mean you're tying a dependency into the header that will result in recompilation when it is switched on or off.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on how you use it. If it's the same project/solution and the compiler is capable of doing full program optimization, it will probably be irrelevant.

If you're distributing the code w/ binaries and the implementation is not visible, and the compiler can't tell it's empty, there will be some (minor) overhead due to the call.

Answer (score 0):

In debug builds this will be called and will have the overall effect of any function call.  In optimized code in general the compiler will omit the call.

As per the comments below.

At the call site the compiler will not be able to determine that the called function has no effect.  If your macro also defined the empty condition inline then the call site would be able to see the function is essentially a noop.

Comment: How will the compiler be able to omit the call? The definition is not in the same TU and I wouldn't assume LTO.

Comment: It can determine that any empty function has no effect and there for just not call it.  Its similar to how the compiler can optimize functions into inlines when optimizing.

Comment: But while compiling the files where the calls are, it cannot know the function has no effect, as it doesn't see its definition or anything.

Comment: Good point.  Whole program optimization would be able to.  Or Profile guided.  But better yet it should be defined inline than there would be no effect.

Answer (score 0):

If you want more certainty that the compiler will optimise the call away, do the following:

Timer.h:

```
class Timer
{
  public:
  void start();
  void printTimeAndRestart(const char* msg);
};

namespace Timing {    static Timer timer; }

#ifndef DO_TIMING
inline void Timer::start() {}
inline void printTimeAndRestart(const char*) {}
#endif
```

Timer.cpp:

```
#ifdef DO_TIMING
//implementation
void Timer::start() { ... };
void Timer::printTimeAndRestart(const char* msg) { ... };
#endif
```

Comment: Yep...That would add more certainty (for some definition of certainty).  Although I get the heebie-jeebies when one arbitrary `#define` added anywhere in the codebase could break something like this.  (Admittedly, the questioner invented that `#define`)

Answer (score 0):

If the functions are defined "inline" (that is, as part of the header file that declareing the class they belong to), then the compiler can avoid generating code for the empty function. If the function is in a .cpp file, the compiler MUST generate code to call the function, as the compiler can't know what the function does [unless the compiler supports "whole program optimization"].

My solution would be to move the functions into the header file, rather than using macros. It's a neater solution, and unless the compiler is absolutely rubbish, it should sort it out as "no code generated".